# Macro button disappears following restart

Tags: vba, button, outlook, outlook-2007

Quick:

A button to execute VBA code disappears after OL2007 is restarted.

Detail:

I have code to mark multiple mails as SPAM from [here](http://www.vboffice.net/de/developers/mehrere-emails-gleichzeitig-als-spam-markieren/). It works as expected.

When I create a button in a ribbon I can use the button as expected.

When I close and restart Outlook the button disappears.

There is just one noticeable effect: when I try to recreate the button, there are no macros listed under the topic macros. But when I open the VB-Editor, I see all the macros. I can re-create the button, again everything works as expected.

I tried to execute Outlook as an administrator: no change - same effect. I thought that it might have to do with writing back some data.

I have other macros, they still operate, also with buttons.

System: win7-64 Home

Comment: How do you customize the Ribbon in Outlook? Do you add a QAT button? You may find the [Customize the Outlook Toolbar, Ribbon or QAT](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/customize-toolbar-ribbon-or-qat/) article helpful.

Comment: I do it with the (rigth click) 'customize commands' -> macro command (I am using the German version, so names might be slightly different), select macro and drag the macro to the place (an existing Menue) I want it to show. It works as expected, but if I close and reopen OL the button is gone.
So it seems to me that something is not permanently stored.
But I have no idea where, and what the reason could be.

Comment: btw, I doning what the in the above link is shown in the video. A have such a button alread done in the past for contacts. But this time it shall bei in the main main window. There I have also some tools which show as expected.

Comment: We are having the exact same issue as you described, but only on my collegue's workstation. On my own PC where the macro was developed, everything works as intended. In our particular case, it looks to be machine related. Both PC's are windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Is there a difference in the antivir Systems or settings?
I have not tried it yet, but I have some "feeling" that this has something to do with some of the security systems running in the background.
E.g. I cant also change settings in some of the gadgets (sidebar), so I suppose that the settings are not written back to disk or so.